# Ping timeout when downloading

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping, timeout

I have a strange behaviour with my router.

When I do nothing on my network, all it's ok when I ping it. I tried with 1000 ping and I get:

> 1000 packets transmitted, 995 packets received, 0.5% packet loss
>   round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = -126.924/4.398/1568.028/52.926 ms

0.5% lost don't seem me very bad (but I'm not a network expert).

But when I'm downloading something, all pings fall in timeout. I tried when I'm downloading ubuntu (1Go):

> 385 packets transmitted, 8 packets received, 97.9% packet loss
>   round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.022/1.636/2.272/0.458 ms

What can be wrong with my router ?
I have some problems when I want to visit websites when I download, why ?

Thanks.

Comment: I use simply my web browser

Comment: How can I saturate a router which can accept more than 10 devices (according to netgear) which only one download ? (3Mo/s for speed). I take it exactly to do more things with devices.